# DB Link from Oracle to MS Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, dblink

I am new to this forum and already searched for 45 minutes to find a solution for my problem. I hope you can help me.
A Gateway to a remote `Microsoft SQL Database` was installed on a Oracle Server (`Oracle 12c`). The `tsnnames.ora` file was appropiately set up.
For the connection, I created a database link (In the Oracle DB) as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK TEL CONNECT TO "fb_B2C" IDENTIFIED BY "passwort" USING 'dg1msql';
```

When I now execute the Select statement:

```
SELECT "name" FROM "sys"."databases"@TEL
```

it shows me the according databases. Among others, I can see the `AB_Colors` database.
Now, I want to select a view in the `AB_Colors` database.

Due to the fact I can connect to this database via Excel, I know that in the database AB_Colors, there are 10 Views(A,B,C,..). I would like to select the View C from the database `AB_Colors` via the DB LInk.

Owner of the View is `b2b`. 
How do i need to formulate the select statement to do it?
I already tried different writings:

```
SELECT * FROM b2b.C@TEL;

SELECT * FROM "AB_colors"."b2b"."C"@TEL;

SELECT * FROM [AB_Colors].[b2b].[C]@TEL;
```

The common error message is: `View/Table does not exist`

I highly appreciate your help,

Fedja

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct format

```
SELECT * FROM "b2b"."C"@TEL;
```

The issue maybe because the database you want to select from is not the one specified in the gateway for dg1msql.  You can't add the database name to the query so you must specify it in the gateway connection.

This is defined in

```
$ORACLE_HOME/dg4msql/admin/initdg4msql.ora
```

where you should check `HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO`

Comment: Hi Lunc,
thanks already for your answer. Do I have to specify it on the Client Level or on the database server (I have to ask the DB Admin)

Comment: On the database level in the Gateway home.

Comment: `HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO=host_name:port_name//database_name` https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/otgiw/init-param-gateway.html#GUID-F5EE8DA1-1429-4CED-8920-EE995141821B